# Force USB-C keyboard to wake up

Tags: mac, keyboard, usb, apple-silicon

My MacBook Pro M1 is connected to USB-C EPOMAKER keyboard directly, after waking up, the keyboard just does not work, I have to unplug it and plug it again.

Any idea if this issue was resolved?

Comment: Have you tried contacting their technical support?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you on Ventura? It could be a bug in a new feature called "Accessory Security": _On portable Mac computers with Apple silicon, new USB accessories require user approval before the accessory can communicate with macOS for connections wired directly to the USB-C port. (...) You can change the security configuration in System Settings>Security and Privacy>Security. The initial configuration is Ask for new accessories. (...) Approved devices can connect to a locked Mac for up to three days._ Can you check System Settings>Security and Privacy>Security?